# Do we want a flag to manually push questions into the help&improvement queue?

Tags: discussion, flags, help-improvement

Today I came across a post that really needed major reformatting, but I was not very familiar with the topic so I didn't really want to edit myself.

If I am not mistaken only questions from **Triage** end up in the **Help&Improvement** queue. Do we want a mechanism to flag questions for **Help&Improvement**, very similar to the concept of `VLQ`?

Answer (score 5):

First off, you could just edit it. I mean, you're looking at it, you have full editing privileges, you presumably *know what's wrong with it*... Why involve other people?

If you can't figure out how to fix it, and it *really* needs to be fixed (as in, if it can't be fixed, it will have to be deleted), then you can flag it as Very Low Quality - this will put it in Triage, which *might* result in it being sent to the Help & Improvement queue. It results in several other people having to be involved, and might well result in the question just being closed though, so don't just use this as a way to lazily ask others to fix typos or formatting issues that you could fix yourself

Comment: In this special case I was actually looking for a solution to "lazily ask others" to do the editing work for me - I was not really interested in the technology so I decided not to read the (rather long) question. But the question was obviously badly tagged and the code was not well formatted, so it was clear that editing is required. In the end I just left without any action. That's where I came up with the idea.

Comment: Doesn't it seem counterproductive to flag as very low quality? If it moves to the improvement queue then the post is judged to not be very low quality and the flag is disputed or declined.

Comment: Doesn't it seem counterproductive to flag *as anything* if your goal is to **edit**, @TravisJ?

Comment: @Shog9 - Yes, which is why flags should be used for content that is meant to be deleted and is incapable of being salvaged. Not sure why anyone would suggest flagging content for removal that should be edited.

Comment: You might wanna re-read the second paragraph here, @Travis.

Comment: @Shog9 - Maybe in theory it works like you describe. But in practice it just results in handfuls of disputed or declined flags.

Comment: That doesn't really contradict what I'm describing, @Travis. I *did* say not to use it as a way of just assigning edits to someone else; if no one else cares enough to edit (or close) either then your flag isn't helpful and its status will reflect that.

Comment: VLQ flags go to Triage now? I thought they went to the VLQ review.

Comment: @apaul34208 on questions, yes.